# Tailwind CSS horizontal overflow wrapping

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css

I have a small little div in my project which looks like so;

```
<div class="mb-4">
    <div x-cloak x-show="output.length" class="relative bg-gray-800 text-gray-200 rounded p-4 text-xs">
        <pre x-html="output"></pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

A little bit of javascript adds a . to the output on each foreach loop.

Im using AlpineJS for the javascript, I am adding the dots similar to the following;

```
<script>
    window.getApp = function() {
        return {
            output: '',

            echo(string) {
                this.output += string + '<br>';
            },
            loadApp() {
                var i;

                for (i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
                    this.echo('.');
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The issue that i am having is if the dots go wider than the width of the output, it doesn't wrap, it just keeps on going out of screen. Is there any way to automatically wrap the line when it hits the edge of the container. See image below;

[image]

Comment: would you mind sharing the recreatable code to look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vanilla CSS solution would be to add `word-wrap: break-word;`

```js
var boo = document.getElementById("boo");
function add() {
  boo.textContent += ".";
}
setInterval(add, 100)
```

```css
#boo {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="boo"></div>
```

Comment: For some reason this doesnt seem to be working for me.

Comment: Actually ... I wrote it wrong ... This does work. Thank you so much!